# Removing the exceeding data from matrices in order to have the same length

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to **matrix A** and **B** with complimentary data of charging and discharging of batteries. **Matrix B** collect much more points than **matrix A**. I want to put some columns of these matrices together before processing the data. To do so I have to remove the exceeding points of the **matrix B** at the end of each charge and discharge.

Here is the code I'm trying to do but I have a problem to put the data in the exact rows in order to have a continuous table.

```
A = Matrix1;
B = Matrix2;
phase=sign(B(1,7));
tab(:,1) = A(index_star:index_end,1);
tab(:,3) = naninterp(A( index_star:index_end,5))/1000;
for i =1:150:length(tab)
    if  tab(i,3) >=x &&  sign(B( i,7))==phase %Collect the data corresponding to the charge
        tab(1:i,2) = tab(1:i,8) ;
        tab(1:i,4) = tab(1:i,7)*1000;
        j=i;
        break
    elseif  tab(i,3) <x &&  sign(B( i,7))~=phase %collect the discharge data
        tab(1:i,2) = B(1:i,8) ;
        tab(1:i,4) = B(1:i,7)*1000;
        j=i;
        break
    elseif  tab(i,3) <2  &&  sign(B(i,7))==phase %data dont match, so delete the exceeding B data
        k=i;
        while sign(B( i,7))==phase
            k1=k+1
            break
        end
        tab(j:k1,2) = B(j:k1,8) ;
        tab(i,4) = B(j:k1,7)*1000;
    elseif  tab(i,3) >=x && sign(B( i,7))~=phase %data dont match, so delete the exceeding B data
        k3=i;
        while sign(B( i,7))~=phase
            j=j+1
            break
            k4=k3;
        end
        tab(i,2) = B(k4,8) ;
        tab(i,4) = B(k4,7)*1000;
    end
end
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to note that you require 2 counters. Something you tried with those `i` and `j` (and even `k` for some reason), but then you used just `i` in the end.
I used `iA` as index of `A` matrix and `iB` as index of `B` matrix. Clearer than just `i` and `j`.

```
for iA = 1 : length(A)
   if (A(iA) and B(iB) datapoint matches)
      tab ... 
   else
      while(~datapoint_matches) % Same condition as above.
         iB = iB + 1;
      end
   end
end
```

Alternative that requires a single loop is to go by B and if datapoint matches, add it, else simply continue with the B loop without advancing iA counter.

```
for iB = 1 : length(B)
   if (datapoint_matches) % The same as in upper case.
      tab(iA, n:m) = B(iB, :); % or whatever.
      iA = iA + 1; 
   else % Data point does not match.
       % NOP - we are ignoring extra B points.
   end
end
```

There are likely way faster Matlab approaches that ditch loops, but the above should be easier to understand and also much faster than any Matlab code if you put it in mex, so I don't think you should bother making your code harder to understand for you.
The only "optimization" I really advise you to do immediately is to first allocate space for a matrix - that you don't extend existing `tab` when you are adding `B` data points, but make `tab` big enough in the first place. It will also be much better if you ever want to port code to say C/C++, which often fails in a nasty way when you are dirtying space outside of the allocated array bounds :)

Comment: @mimi, As long as the loop is not nested,  I wouldn't bother converting it to MEX. There is no guarantee that it _will_ be faster in this case, and it may even make things slower.